# Button click to load dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

Trying to load datatable on button click and table not populated, getting blank table. Tried below code, please suggest me the solution,

```
onSubmit(){
   const that = this;
    this.dtOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
            dataTablesParameters, {}
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.persons = resp.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: []
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName', class: 'none' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
    };
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-server-side-1264-q2fkhj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: do you really need  to place the button inside the form? because the form has no additional input.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `dtOptions.ajax` only gets called the first time, i.e. in the example that I assume you are following, they use `ngOnInit` instead of a button trigger.

Comment: @uingtea, yeah tried to keep button outside the form as well. Still getting same issue.

Comment: @RJM, Yeah example showing like ngOnInit, but I'm trying to get the table onSubmit button click.

Comment: Just looking at one of the [examples](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender) from that npm package, would something like this be what you want?  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-server-side-1264-wgmh2m?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @RJM, thank you very much for the your support, this approach is working fine.

Comment: @Rajasekhar great, glad that works for you. I'm not close enough to this library to properly answer this question, so could I suggest that once you have a fully working solution, you post an answer so that others can see what you did.